# Animate arbitrary value with angular 7

Tags: angular, animation

I'm trying to (for the lack of a better word) 'animate' a number from 0 to a set number in a timely manner (and preferably include some kind of an easing function on the whole thing).

I know angular 7 has a built in animation framework but i can't figure out how to use it outside of the context of direct view manipulation.

The end result is intended to update a presented value as a running number until reaching the target.

Is there a way to do this with angular or is there an external library that can handle this kind of tasks

Answer (score 0):

I needed that in my angular project too. As I use ngx charts and some charts has such an upcounting feature.. I just copied the code and changed it so it fits in my project.

[link to ngx charts upcounter](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/master/src/common/count/count.directive.ts)

[demo](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/advanced-pie-chart)

It's not a copy and go code but it will lead you in the right direction. If you need any help with the code just add a comment :)